# convert Git hub fork to npm package

Tags: angular, github, npm, fork

i am using ng2-select package and i want to edit the code of this package to allow disable item inside the list .

i have made the edit and its working fine , now my issue is each time i make NPM install it will remove my edit and bring back the original package code .

i have tried to publish the package using npm publish but i could not do it correctly i kept getting an error saying that i am not the correct user or owner of this package.

how can i re publish the package with my code and add it to package.json file?

Comment: You do not own this package, so you can not publish it officially. As the error message says, you do not have permission.

Comment: ok then what is the use of the fork at github? can i use the files from the fork in my application without converting them to npm package ?

Answer (score 1):

You can bypass NPM and install directly from your GitHub fork:

`npm install git+https://git@github.com/yourname/yourrepo.git --save`

If you want to install with NPM, you'll need actually to put your fork on NPM by publishing it as a new package (provided the package's license is open). See [How to publish a package](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/publishing-npm-packages)

Comment: thank you so much for your reply , however i tried to do this and i get the folders empty in node_modules. 
can you please try it and let me know if it work?
https://github.com/ahmadkhalaf1/ng2-select

Comment: component/select is empty